# Read serial data java in one line

Tags: java, serial-port, line

I'm making a project with a rs485 module.
Every time the module sends data to my com port i want to catch that data.
And that's works, I can catch it. But when I catch it I see it in multiple lines.

My data starts every time with `*` and ends with `#`.

Can you help my to catch the data in only 1 line ? Thanks !

```
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
    //if(event.isRXCHAR() && event.getEventValue() > 0) {
    try {

        String receivedData = serialPort.readString(event.getEventValue());
        while (receivedData.charAt(0) == '#') {
            receivedData = receivedData.substring(1, receivedData.length());
        }
        System.out.println("Received response from port: " + receivedData);
    } catch (SerialPortException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error in receiving response from port: " + ex);
    }
    //}
}
```

Comment: `while(receivedData.charAt(0) == '#')` doesn't make much sense. You need read until you get the leading `*`, which should be only one read, and then to keep reading until you get the *trailing* `#`.

Comment: @YCF_L What are you talking about? The post contains input code.

Comment: @YCF_L The OP has already clearly stated that the data starts with `*` and ends with `#`. Still unclear what you're talking about.

Comment: @YCF_L Everything you have asked for was already provided. Please delete all this nonsense.

Comment: @EJP yes but i don't know how to put this together. How can i read in 1 single tring until i get the '#'.

Comment: @YCF_L the data should be *024514AG874# for example , now i get on my first line * , seconds line 0 , third line 4 ...

Comment: Doesn't work , same problem.

Comment: @YCF_L I don't know why you're lecturing me, when you're the one who couldn't even read what was already posted in the question, or in my comment, and what your regular expression has to do it is another mystery. Please stop it.

Comment: Oke can you help me now ? :)

Comment: Can you do **System.out.println(receivedData );**
Before the while loop starts? I want to see if you are receiving the data as a char stream or as a string

Comment: @searcotjabali i dit that , same problem , i get my data in multiple lines. For every carachter 1 line. For example * on line 1 , 3 on line 2 , 8 on line 3 .. And i want *38 .. on 1 line

Comment: @JensG : You have declared receivedData as a string. That means what you are getting from the serial port is a string. It might contain new line characters which makes it look like a character array. Use code in the answer to strip the \n

Comment: @searcotjabalin 'It might contain new line characters which makes it look like a character array' is complete and utter nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read until you get the initial `*`, and then read until you get the final `#`":

```
String ch;
StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer();
while (!(ch = serialPort.readString(1)).equals("*"))
    ;
while (!(ch = serialPort.readString(1)).equals("#"))
    data.append(ch);
return data.toString();
```

You need to add error and EOS handling to this, of course.

Answer (score -1):

If the problem is that you are iterating *receivedData* as a char array then you can do this

```
receivedData = receivedData.substring(receivedData.indexOf('*'), receivedData.indexOf('#'));
```

If you are getting new line characters in the input just use

```
receivedData = receivedData.replaceAll("(\\n)", "");
```

Comment: I might have missed a +1 for the indexOf function.
But I cant remember if the index count is inclusive or exclusive. You will have to try and check

Comment: Doesn't work i get an error while testing , "string index out of range: -1"

Comment: This code only works if the `*` and `#` are present, which is the point at issue.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Take a look at this.
Since you are not running the **String receivedData = serialPort.readString(event.getEventValue());** in a loop, you have to be getting a string. So I am assuming that the string you are getting has **\n** after every character.
Is that assumption correct?
Or is it something else?

Comment: I think you are correct but im not shure , when i start putty for example then i get the data in online , now for the error " string index out of range -1 " i entered +1 in my code but now i have the error " string index out of range -2"

Comment: @JensG Sorry bud. Withouth actually being able to see what is going on, its hard to try and tackle it. While I am good with Java I have very limited experience in reading serial data from ports

Comment: Please copy/paste the code here instead of taking a screenshot.